# Android Studio replacing random files

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0

Android Studio is replacing files in my projects. It mainly affects layout files. Mostly it looks like this:
[image]

Most of the time the app is still able to build and run without errors. I can easily restore these files through Git, but it's really annoying.

This doesn't appear for any reason, like a crash or something like that.

I'm running Android Studio 4.0.1
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6626763, built on June 25, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64

Has anyone encountered something similar and knows how to fix it?

Comment: It's a known bug in android studio nothing to fear about. You can follow these links 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents?noredirect=1&lq=1

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53403502/strange-error-in-colors-xml-file-in-android-studio

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52821567/android-studio-shows-some-mess-in-xml-files


if your code is connected with repository then you can revert your code then this will also be fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the links, I thought I was the only one. Lets hope for a fix then.

Answer (score 0):

Erasing the cache of Android Studio will resolve the issue.
to do this go to `/.AndroidStudio4.0/system/caches/` folder and delete all the files in this folder.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing that issue

copy your code and move it to other directory
then Delete Top 2 folders named(.gradle and .idea)
and also delete all .iml files
then import this project (do not open project use import project)

Answer (score -1):

you can solve this issue >> kindly reinstall android studio . several days before i got this issue .